# Remove first character from each line of a fixed width file using SSIS VB.Net script task

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I need to Remove first character from each line of a fixed width file using SSIS VB.Net script task. could anyone please share the SSIS VB.Net script task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for c# script component:

```
Row.Col1 = Row.Col1.Substring(1);
```

Make sure to add your column as read/write in input section.

That was a direct answer, but since you have fixed width file, I would just have my first column be 1 char and just not use it.

Comment: Position in Substring is 0 based so 1 is start at 2nd position.